How to move the /var folder from one physical disc to another?
I need to unmount the /var folder and move it to a 250GB drive.
When I try to umount /var I get an error Disk is busy, when I try to rename this folder I get the same error.
What would be the correct way for me to move it to a larger disc?
vda    252:0    0   80G  0 disk
└─vda1 252:1    0   80G  0 part /
vdb    252:16   0  100G  0 disk
└─vdb1 252:17   0  100G  0 part /var
vdc    252:32   0  250G  0 disk
└─vdc1 252:33   0  250G  0 part


Assuming Whole Disk Move
As the OP has found out, filesystems cannot be moved when the system is in use. Assuming the OP wants to move a smaller whole disk to a bigger whole disk:

If the bigger disk is IDE/SATA, connect it in your case.

If it's USB it can wait until the end of Step 3


Download the Live CD/USB for your chosen distribution
Boot the Live CD/USB
Choose Try (Distribution) from the Grub Menu or from the "What Would You Like to Do?" Window

If your (Distribution) doesn't have a "Try" option download and create a GParted LiveCD/USB and boot it


Once the "Try" option finishes booting, find the Applications button, and search for GParted.
Click GParted, and let your disks load.

If needed, plug in your USB "bigger" drive, and choose File, Rescan to pick up the device.


Pick the disk with your current OS.  Do the following:

Copy each partition, and paste it one at a time in the bigger disk
Make a note of the UUID's of the new partitions


Mount your OS / partition in /mnt and edit /mnt/etc/fstab to match the new UUID's from step 7.
Reboot and Test


This depends on gpartd being available, which is not always the case. If not. you can have you installed /var mounted as, for instance, /mnt/live/var and the target mounted as /mnt/live/newvar. Then, from the live CD command line, use cd /mnt/live/var; cp -a . /mnt/liv/newvar. Edit /mnt/liv/etc/fstab to mount the new partition as /var. After you conform that everything is working, you can repurpose /dev/sdb1 for other uses.

What I would do:
mkdir /mountpoint/250GB/var
rsync -avP /var/ /mountpoint/250GB/var/
rm -rf /var/*
mount --bind /mountpoint/250GB/var /var

And in /etc/fstab:
/mountpoint/250GB/var /var  bind   0   0


rm -rf /var/* I think the error will occur resource is busy or target is busy or smth like it.
I've tried deleting the folder before, but I did it this way rm -fr /var

Why not change /etc/fstab to mount /dev/vdc1 as /var instead of using the bind mount?
